# Does the sftp in linux get files that are partially being transferred?

Tags: linux, sftp

I have the following setup:

```
A   ==[sftp put]==>   B   <==[sftp get]==   C
```

1. [server A] puts files to [server B] using sftp put command.
2. [server C] has a batch that tries to forward all the files posted by [server A] to intermediate [server B].
3. Every minute or so, [server C] runs a script that gets the file from intermediate [server B].
4. For each file transferred to C, the batch file will delete the
   file from B.

My concern is, does the sftp request allows (step 3) mget of files that are partially being transferred by another sftp command (step 1)?

Is there a way to only mget completely transferred files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really doubt sftp concerned with atomic transfer, and I think locking not available until v. 5

you have to somehow indicate that transfer is done, some sort of complete file, and based on this build your logic.

more ideas:
1. upload into an "upload"  folder, move after complete or rename

Comment: yeah, I am already planning to check a file footer marker just to see if the file is complete. But am wondering if there is a better way. Thanks for the reply.